# Suggested sequence of responses in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have such values in the letter column:

```
A, B, C, D, E, **X**.
```

I would like the select to return to me such an order of

```
A, B, **X**, C, D, E.
```

I tried with `ORDER BY`, but I don't know if it's a good way, or it should be `SELECT Top 2` and next...

Comment: If you need a guaranteed order the **only** way is `ORDER BY` - you say you've tried this and it works so is there still a question here?

Comment: Can you please clarify how you want the letters ordered (as in, what's the rule)? always alphabetically, but comes third? Or is it that the last letter should always appear third in the list?

Comment: Yes, i want result when X letter is after D, and next rest of letters

Comment: So, you need your own non-standard order on what is essential a char column?

Comment: Do you want Xerox after Berlin and before Celsius?

Comment: Do you want Axel before Andorra?

Answer (score 2):

If it's only one character:

```
order by case when MyColumn < 'C' then 1
              when MyColumn = 'X' then 2
              else 3
         end,
         MyColumn
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it will sort Axel after Andorra - which may, or may not be what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a case expression to re-position the 'X' between 'B' and 'C' as follows.

```
order by case when MyColumn = 'X' then 'BB' else MyColumn end
```

Comment: Yeah, pretty much the only way you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should assign a numeric value to each of the possible values in order to get them in the desired way. It could be something like

```
order by case when column = 'A' then 1 
              when column = 'B' then 2
              when column = 'C' then 3
              when column = 'X' then 4
              ...
              else 99999999
end
```